# Python Pandas: Adicionar coluna de outro DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

**Resumo do problema:**
Eu gostaria de saber o melhor método de adicionar uma coluna de um data frame em outro.

Possuo dois Dataframes como do exemplo abaixo:

```
df1 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}
base_dados = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(base_dados)

    Id  Fruta
0   01  Maçã
1   02  Abacaxi
2   03  Banana
3   04  Laranja
4   05  Morango
```

E o segundo Dataframe

```
df2 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango'], "AREA":['Area 01', 'Area 02', 'Area 02', 'Area 03', 'Area 05']}
base_dados = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(base_dados)

    Id  Fruta    AREA
0   01  Maçã     Area 01
1   02  Abacaxi  Area 02
2   03  Banana   Area 02
3   04  Laranja  Area 03
4   05  Morango  Area 05
```

Gostaria de um método que acrescente a coluna "AREA" do df2 no df1.

**O que eu já tentei:**
Eu tentei a função `apply` e `map`

Apply:

```
df1['AREA'] = df2['AREA'].apply(lambda x: x)
```

Map

```
df1['AREA'] = df1['id'].map(df2['AREA'])
```

Comment: Olá, seu código foi formatado para uma melhor aparência. Caso queira, é possível editar a postagem. Para isso basta clicar no botão [editar]https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/530059/edit). Também removi mensagens de cumprimentos [saiba o motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dados

Fiz umas pequenas alterações nos seus dados por razão que eu não entendi de onde você tirou a variável data

#### df1

```
   df1 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
   display(df1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### df2

```
df2 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango'], "AREA":['Area 01', 'Area 02', 'Area 02', 'Area 03', 'Area 05']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
display(df2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### df1 com a coluna AREA

```
df1['AREA'] = df2['AREA']
df1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa tarde Kaique, suas alterações estão corretas, o problema é que quando eu uso sua sugestão, está vindo informações NaN ao invés dos dados.

Comment: Opa Bruno, você copiou todos os meus códigos que eu coloquei na resposta e executou ?

Comment: Sim, no codigo acima eu maquiei as informações para nao colocar dados da empresa na qual trabalho. Mas sim, transformei elas em um Dataframe único e coloquei o código acima.

Comment: Copia o código que eu elaborei nessa plataforma http://codepad.org/F6M54ZJh e executa

Comment: Kaique, descobri o meu erro, quando eu estava criando no data frame, eu precisava dar um .reset_index(), resolveu o problema, Mas a sua logica está totalmente correta, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Fico feliz em te ajudar. :)